# What does char(10) do in a dynamic t-sql string?

Tags: t-sql

I have a dynamic sql string in a existing procedure. What does the char(10) do?

> Set @SelectStr = @SelectStr + ' And FC.FCode = ''' + @FCode + '''' +
>   CHAR(10)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`CHAR(10)` is the character represented by ASCII code 10, which is a Line Feed (\n) so its a new line.

(Although its not the windows standard new line which is Carriage Return + Line Feed `CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)`)

In your example its probably just used to make the string more readable when its printed out.